# Can't get XPath query to return the right nodeset

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I've got an xml file that looks like this:

```
<Records>
<Record>
 <table>
  <Row>
   <col1>value1</col1>
  </Row>
 </table>
</Record>
<Record>
 <table>
  <Row>
   <col1>value2</col1>
  </Row>
 </table>
</Record><Record>
 <table>
  <Row>
   <col1>value3</col1>
  </Row>
 </table>
</Record>
</Records>
```

What I need is to select all the ROW nodes, across all records, so I'm using something like this:

```
rowiterator = Me.XMLDocument.CreateNavigator.Evaluate("//table/Row")
```

which is working, but it returns a NodeIterator that only contains the first Row node in the first record!?!

As far as I can tell, that's the proper syntax for an xpath expression of "return all Row nodes with a parent table name anywhere in the document".

I've got to be missing something simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: So when you iterate through using MoveNext() or a foreach statement, you only get to the first node before it breaks?

Comment: If you tried to go along the lines of this [`XPathNodeIterator` sample on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.aspx)?

Comment: @Ken that's right, When I check the count from the NodeIterator that's returned, it shows 1. I'd have expected it to show 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`XPathNavigator.Select` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea193ac.aspx) and loop through the iterator. Use the [`XPathNodeIterator.Current` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.current.aspx) to access the current `XPathNavigator` object in the loop.

```
Dim iter = xmldoc.CreateNavigator().Select("//table/Row")
While (iter.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(iter.Current.Value)
End While
```

Comment: Tried that too. When I check iter.Count, I see 1, not 3 like I'd expect. and sure enough, when I iterate through, I get only the row from the first "record" element. Very strange.

Comment: Ugh. You know. I should learn not to try and code with a splitting headache. Ahmed was spot on. I missed a typo earlier in my code. Thanks!

Comment: @drventure glad to hear it (not about the headache!)... had me wondering what else might be up :)